# How to modify the href of a Ruby Mechanize::Page::Link before clicking it

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I have a page retrieved using a Mechanize session and I need to click on a Mechanize::Page::Link as in this example:

```
my_link = @session.page.link_with(:id => "aPageLink")
# my_link.class == Mechanize::Page::Link
.
.
.
@session.click(my_link)
```

However, I need to modify the uri used in the link **before** it is clicked.

```
my_link = @session.page.link_with(:id => "aPageLink")
# my_link.class == Mechanize::Page::Link
.
.
.
# modify my_link here
.
.
.
@session.click(my_link)
```

How would I do that?

I should add that I've tried the following already [should have mentioned these earlier then some unrelenting soul wouldn't have marked down my question!]...

```
my_link.href = "my/modified/uri"
my_link['href'] = "my/modified/uri"
```

Comment: What have you tried? Mechanize uses Nokogiri internally to parse the HTML, and Nokogiri gives you access to change the DOM, making it possible to manipulate the URL inside the HTML. Those steps are well documented on the internet.

Comment: `Link#click` does the same thing as `Mechanize#get` so the `get` would be a more sensible approach

Answer (score 0):

Solution from pguardiario's suggestion is as follows.

```
my_link = @session.page.link_with(:id => "aPageLink")

# modify my_link
modified_link = my_link.href
modified_link.sub!(/modification/, '')

# @session.click(my_link) <-- now replaced with following line
@session.get modified_link, [], my_link.referer
```

Many thanks!